# Цикл с заданными параметрами при get запросе

Tags: python, django, web-apps

Работаю с джанго. На первый get запрос создается объект модели CurrentGame с заданными полями, в котором имеется поле small_blind_seat(номер места). После завершения всех операция, посылается новый get запрос и создается новый объект модели CurrentGame. Нужно чтобы поле small_blind_seat для каждого нового объекта модели Game увеличивалось на 1 и так пока не станет равной 6, потом опять с 1. В голову только приходит переменная, которая будет увеличиваться на 1, после каждого get запроса, но у меня ничего не вышло с ее описанием, вернее не знаю как сделать так чтобы она увеличивалась после нового запроса.

```
class StartGame(View):

def get(self, request):       
    game_1_start = CurrentGame.objects.create(
        small_blind=1,
        big_blind=2,
        bank=3,
        small_blind_seat=i,            
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понимаю зачем Вам это. Но ладно.
Сохраняйте свой счетчик "i" где-нибудь (в БД хотя бы) с дефолтным значением 0.
Перед тем, как создавать объект модели CurrentGame, проверяйте равен он 6 или нет. Если не равен увеличивайте на 1. Если равен: i = 1.